# Fetching attributes of a POJO in generic way

Tags: java, java-8

I am fetching attributes of an object as List, where AvsAttribute is as follows:

```
     class AvsAttribute {
        String attrName,
        String value
    }
```

I am fetching the attribute values for any entity as follows, as I did not want to use reflection, that's why did like that:

```
 @Override
  public List<AvsAttribute> getAttributes(List<String> attributeNameList, final @NonNull T entity)
  throws JsonProcessingException, JSONException {
  List<AvsAttribute> attributeList = new ArrayList<>();
  objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
  String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(entity);
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
  Iterator<String> keysItr = jsonObject.keys();
  while (keysItr.hasNext()) {
    String key = keysItr.next();
    String value = jsonObject.get(key).toString().trim();
  attributeList.add(AvsAttribute.builder().name(key).value(value).build());
   }
  if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(attributeNameList)) {
    return attributeList.stream().filter(item -> attributeNameList.contains(item.getName()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
return attributeList;
```

}

But I want to make AvsAttribute generic like below:

```
      class AvsAttribute<T> {
        String attrName,
        T value
    }
```

But I cannot figure out what change should I do to the above getAttributes() function so that it works with above generic class.

Answer (score 0):

I think it already works with a generic type parameter. You need to setup the `.value(String value)` function in `AvsAttribute` builder to safely parse a given string into type `T`.
Then, you can rest assured that the following line will correctly fetch the generic attribute value:

`AvsAttribute.builder().name(key).value(value).build()`

Does that make sense?
Anyway, Good luck with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use wildcard `?` in `attributeList` declaration and `return` type.